# How do I use samsung opensource kernel for AOSP?

Tags: kernel, android-source, android-7.0-nougat

I got the source code form opensource.samsung.com, and I compiled the kernel successfully.

I want to know that how do I use the kernel to build AOSP for my phone?

And the samsung kernel is based on Android 6.0.1, can I port Android 7.1.1 to my phone or Only Android 6.0.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify this

export TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL=$your_kernel_path/arch/arm/boot/zImage-dtb

and then you do :

make bootimage

this will generate you a boot.img in out/target/product/.../ that you can fastboot flash boot boot.img

You can try Android 6.0.1. Do you have Samsung patches to that A 6.0.1 ? You will need a serial connection to early boot console printouts and fix one by one errors that can occur.

Or try this: setup your own device with this:
device/common/populate-new-device.sh

Comment: I'm not totally understand, but thanks for the answer, blogs about it would be appreciated